# Why does me changing the time have an opposite effect on my output graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, sampling, subplot

Here is my code:

```
clear all;
%% Load the earthquake data file
load ECE350_Earthquake_Demo.mat
tearth = 0:dt:(length(d)-1)*dt;
t1 = tearth';
%% Play the sound of the earthquake
sound(d, fs)
figure,subplot(3, 1, 1); % 3 subplots in a 3x1 matrix
plot(t1,d) %% plots f(t)
title('First Subplot f(t)')

subplot(3, 1, 2);
plot(t1*2, d) %% plots f(2t)
title('Second Subplot f(2t)')

subplot(3, 1, 3);
plot(t1*(1/2), d) %% plots f(t/2)
title('Third Subplot f(t/2)')

xlim([0 20]);
orient landscape
delete 'Demo_plot1.pdf'
print -dpdf 'Demo_plot1'
```

This code loads in an earthquake data file and plots the output onto a graph.

I am to plot three different subplots vertically, and plot f(t), f(2t), and f(t/2) respectively.

f(2t) should compress the graph, and f(t/2) should expand the graph, naturally.
My code does the opposite - f(2t) compresses, and f(t/2) expands (t1*2 and t1/2 is how I am implementing this).

The output format is fine, and everything works. These two graphs are just switched.

Why is this?

Comment: `plot(t*2,d)` doesn't plot `f(2*t)`. Imagine `t=[1 2 3 4 5]`, then `plot(t,d)` would have x coordinates 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. `plot(t*2,d)` would have x coordinates 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and so would appear stretched out.

Comment: That's what I thought it might be doing. That was the only way I could think of to implement that. Would I have to maybe change something about the variable when I declare it? Rather than changing it in the subplots?

Comment: Just do it the opposite way to what you have been doing, i.e. `plot(t1/2,d)` for `f(2*t)` and vice versa.

Comment: Is that not just forcing it to look like what I want? Would that actually give me the real graph of f(2t) and f(t/2)?

Comment: Yes, it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to see that `f(2t)` really does compress functions in MATLAB, just like you think it should:

```
t = 0:.1:2*pi;
figure
hold on
plot(t, sin(t))
plot(t, sin(2*t))
plot(t, sin(t/2))
legend({'sin(t)', 'sin(2t)', 'sin(t/2)'})
```

In my example, this works nicely because `sin` is *continuous*: it can take any value of `t` as input. In your case, things are a bit more complicated because `d` is *discrete*: there is `d(1)`, `d(2)`, ..., but there is no `d(.5)`.

If you "just want to see the right plots", let's think of `d` as being samples of a continuous function `f`, such that `d(n) = f(dt * n)` for integers `n`. Then for the plots, pick your `t`s so that you never need values of `f` between the ones you have:

```
t2 = t1 * 2;
plot(t2, d)
```

plots f(t/2) because when we plot the `i`th point, the t value is `t2(i)` = `t1(i) * 2` and the f(t) value is `d(i)` = `f(dt * i)` = `f(t1(i))`.

```
t3 = t1 / 2;
plot(t3, d)
```

plots f(t * 2) because when we plot the `i`th point, the t value is `t3(i)` = `t1(i) / 2` and the f(t) value is `d(i)` = `f(dt * i)` = `f(t1(i))`.